# Forming a sub-sequence of certain digit from given array

Tags: algorithm

I had a contest where the question was to find the possible K digits of valid numbers from an array with N number of items.

For instance,

3       `-> N (Number of items in Array)`

1 2 3   `->A (The array itself constituting N items)`

2       `-> K (This is the given number of digits to form)`

#### Output should be like

[0, 1] = 12

[0, 2] = 13

[1, 0] = 21

[1, 2] = 23

[2, 0] = 31

[2, 1] = 32

What could be the logic I guess `dynamic problem` can solve this problem but I would be glad if I get some help.

Comment: Is this on-going contest? If not, what have you tried?

Comment: @PhamTrung I had that yesterday. I came up with some ideas but that eventually failed.

Comment: What is the expected output? all possible numbers or just a count? what is the constraints for the problem? Could you provide a link to the original statement if possible?

Comment: @Prashant Brute Force is fine however all I want now is just get an idea to solve this. However solution of this using Brute Force could  take I believe O(n * k)

Comment: @PhamTrung the problem in the contest was asked to print just the number of possible numbers of K digits that can be generated from the array. But I need to see this output that I've chosen. For now just consider the problem description is all the items inside the ``array`` is of ``Integer``.

Comment: These are the "k-permutations of n". There are `n!/(n-k)!`. See  https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=k%20permutations%20of%20n and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n

Comment: At that case, the solution will be different, with different time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

We can formulate a recursive function which can prints us all the possible K digit number from the given array of single digit integers. Ideone link: https://ideone.com/RTNz2o

```
def gen(A, K, arr = []):
    if len(arr) == K:
        print (arr, "=", "".join([str(A[i]) for i in arr]))
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        val = A[i]
        if val == 0 and len(arr) == 0:
            # We don't want numbers starting with 0
            continue
        if i in arr:
            # We don't want to include the same element again
            continue
        arr.append(i)
        gen(A, K, arr)
        arr.pop()

gen([1, 2, 3], 2)
```

Comment: Nellex thanks for your contribution but I receive RecursionError by running this  script. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @bikashdas can you let me know about the case for which it's throwing RecursionError?

Comment: I am running the script against the same inputs that you had written in the IDE youself. I believe there is something wrong with the number of stack frames allowed to have in the stack, isn't it?

Comment: @bikashdas I guess your recursion limit is too low, does this blog helps? https://pythontips.com/2013/08/31/fixing-error-maximum-recursion-depth-reached/